# How to get xml tag names in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

can any one help me how to get tag names in my script.In below code i need to get mbrSqncNum?help me out...

```
<Id>059A670</healthCardId> 
<subscriberId>059A625</subscriberId> 
<mbrSqncNum>10</mbrSqncNum>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have valid XML (unlike in your question where there's no root node and mismatched tags), and assuming it's stored in a String variable:

```
def xml = '''<doc>
            |    <healthCardId>059A670</healthCardId> 
            |    <subscriberId>059A625</subscriberId> 
            |    <mbrSqncNum>10</mbrSqncNum> 
            |</doc>'''.stripMargin()
```

You can then parse this XML using:

```
def doc = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )
```

(if it's in a file, you can use this instead)

```
def doc = new XmlParser().parse( xmlFile )
```

Now it's unclear from your question exactly what it is you want...  To print out all the tag names, you can do:

```
// prints '[doc, healthCardId, subscriberId, mbrSqncNum]'
println doc.'**'*.name()
```

(the same thing in longer form would be)

```
// prints '[doc, healthCardId, subscriberId, mbrSqncNum]'
println doc.breadthFirst()*.name()
```

Or to get the value of the tag `mbrSqncNum`, you can do:

```
// prints '10'
println doc.mbrSqncNum.text()
```

Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Hi..Tim..thanks for answering...here i want to validate my tags by name using assertions...can u plz answer for this also...thanks in advance..

Comment: @hemachandra I don't know what you mean :-( can you explain?

Comment: @hemachandra You mean like `assert doc.mbrSqncNum.text() == '10'`? (which works), or `assert [ 'doc', 'healthCardId', 'subscriberId', 'mbrSqncNum' ].every { it in doc.'**'*.name() }` (which also works)? Or something else?